# Android onBackPress call JavaScript function or exit Android application

Tags: javascript, android

I built an Android app using webview.
I create a button on HTML page so can popover some div container. The problem is, when I press the back button, the app continues to exit. My purpose if there is div content, the app will hide the div and process will stop without exiting the app. And if no div is displayed, then the app will exit.
that my Android code

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.cover);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",1500);       
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.loadUrl("javascript:xxx()"); 
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

And my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function xxx(){
reader.dom.find('controls_contents_container').style.display = 'none';
}
```

My app worked just well except it exists when div is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

`super.onDestroy();`

from onBackPressed() method. In case you want the application to finish after back button is pressed call

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: can android detect whether the div is displayed in html?

Comment: For more complex controls you need to implement WebViewClient/WebChromeClient.